# WPF Path vs Image png jpg

Tags: wpf, image, bitmap, vector-graphics

Consider a `Button` composed of many graphical elements (and `Path`) drawn on `Canvas`. Why is it better to use the `Path` and other elements to build an image in that `Button` than assigning a custom `Bitmap` to it?

I know one advantage, "the path is a vector image". But if I'm not planning to zoom, why should I use it in place of my custom .png, .ico and .jpg images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a Path makes it less likely your button will look blurry on different DPIs, which often happens with bitmaps.

Comment: And what concerns different Screen types? LCD vs CRT?

Comment: CRTs aren't such a problem, it's the DPI which is the problem in genral. The problem may become slightly more obvious on LCDs due to ClearType technology ehich tries to make it better, but usually makes wpf blur even worse.